# How do I skip, select, top on the $expand in OData?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

How do I skip, select, top on the `$expand` in OData? Why the following is not working?

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(s2sx534tmya3oqnyfxumtyl1))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Friends($select=Emails&$top=1&$skip1)
```

But if I use only either `$select` or `$top` or `$skip` in the expand it works. For example, the followings works. Why the above is not working? I assume this is a Odata limitation.

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(s2sx534tmya3oqnyfxumtyl1))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Friends($select=Emails)

http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(s2sx534tmya3oqnyfxumtyl1))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Friends($top=1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the expand you need to use semicolons to separate the different options instead of ampersands. This URL should work:

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(s2sx534tmya3oqnyfxumtyl1))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Friends($select=Emails;$top=1;$skip=1)
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent for OData V2 to use $skip and $top for $expand?